# np.arange with Array input

Tags: arrays, numpy, range

I'm looking to create multiple ranges at once given length values stored as an array.

Example:

```
lengths = np.array([1, 5, 10])
```

Create ranges:

```
ranges = np.arange(lengths)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Alternatively, I could also use a solution with *np.linspace* passing an array of steps number as the *num* parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: `np.linspace` accepts arrays for the start and stop, but `num` must be a scalar.  If the steps are the same, the ranges are linear scalings of each other.  But if you expect different size arrays you have to use python iteration/comprehension - with either `arange` or `linspace`.

Comment: `numpy` is optimized for "rectangular" arrays, not "ragged" ones.

Comment: You are completely right about the "ragged" arrays. I didn't properly think about the multiple output array lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you need is a list comprehension?

```
lengths = np.array([1, 5, 10])
ranges = [np.arange(length) for length in lengths]
```